# Is it possible to view the reference count for contexts and command queues in openCL?

Tags: reference, queue, opencl, counter

I want to view the reference counters for these things so I can be sure that they were deleted. Is it possible?

It is mentioned here:
http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clReleaseContext.html
and
http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clReleaseCommandQueue.html

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be hard for you to follow your links to the functions that let you get information about contexts and command queues (including their reference counts), but it is never valid to check a reference count when it is already zero, because the object may have already been deallocated, invalidating your pointer and setting you up for a segfault if you try to dereference the pointer.

Comment: how do you check a reference count? Manually you mean?